# ASP.NET: Send mail with background image does not appear in the mail?

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to send some HTML in a mail message

I have a td that has a CssClass with background image.

when I checked the received mail I found that the background image didn't appear.

I tried to force the background image to the **TD** using the deprecated **background** attribute but nothing changed.

is there any workaround for this problem ?

thanks

Comment: Look at the source of the e-mail and look at what the url for the background is and try accessing it using a browser. It is possible that you are using a relative URL rather than an absolute one.

Comment: What email client/program are you using to test the email?

Comment: Ok guys here's what I found. I'm testing on Hotmail,Gmail,Yahoo and Outlook 2007.
When I use the full url of the images the Images appear in Hotmail, Yahoo and Outlook but do nt appear in Gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most email clients do not read external css. So assuming your CssClass refers to an external css file it wont work in most email clients. Try putting the css inline is a style tag and see if that works.

Comment: It's something like that: .style1 { background-image: url('http://192.168.98.47/Pictures/banner-bg_05.gif'); background-repeat:repeat-x; }

that's the ip of my machine

then the td has class="style1"

Comment: 192.168.98.47 is an internal IP address you receive through your router. Also you need to include http:// otherwise it will look for a folder called 192.168.98.47

Comment: Like @waleed said you need to have an absoulute url

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Guide to CSS Support in Email Clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).  HTML emails will likely be rendered VERY differently depending on the email client that is being used to view your email.

Outlook 2007/2010 does NOT render background images in HTML emails.  I don't know which email client you are testing with but it is highly likely that the client is not displaying background images.

See the link above and test, test, test, test.